# Vue.js raw HTML within attribute

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

Is there a way to output raw HTML to a tags attributes rather than content?

Example:

```
<input :placeholder="data.raw-html-message"/>

...

data.raw-html-message = "some text&hellip;"
```

`v-html` seems to only output it to the innerHTML of the tag and the triple curly braces have been removed in version 2.

Currently with a standard `v-bind` the output is:

`<input placeholder="Message&hellip;" />`

and the HTML entity is not interpreted when displayed in the browser.

Example here: https://jsfiddle.net/cdsm22q8/1/

Comment: I have no clue on how to do this and I can't find any documentation examples for this either. If you really want to go this route this might help you out though: https://github.com/mathiasbynens/he Probably not the answer you are looking for though.

Comment: You probably shouldn't be allowed to do that in general but you can use the unicode equivalent instead `\u2026`

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you parse it with own function?

```
function parse_entities(string){
  return unescape(string);
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/t8v7cre1/